# MPAndroidChart, axis scale respecting the maximum real values

Tags: kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am using the chart library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/)  in Kotlin

Everything is working correctly, `but I have a problem with the axis scales. In my graph my maximum values are as follows:

`X axis: 1947.7872f`

`Y axis: 861.5f`

But when the graph is made the X axis should be larger than the Y axis, but in my graph it almost shows the same. I need the axes to have the scale respecting the real numerical values of both.

My code to make the graph is the following:

```
   private fun setupLineChartData() {
        val yVals = ArrayList<Entry>()
        yVals.add(Entry(0f, 241.5f, "0"))
        yVals.add(Entry(162.3156f, 323.9f, "1"))
        yVals.add(Entry(324.6312f, 529.6f, "2"))
        yVals.add(Entry(486.9468f, 738.2f, "3"))
        yVals.add(Entry(649.2624f, 839.6f, "4"))
        yVals.add(Entry(811.578f, 860.8f, "5"))
        yVals.add(Entry(973.8936f, 861.5f, "6"))
        yVals.add(Entry(1136.2092f, 860.8f, "7"))
        yVals.add(Entry(1298.5248f, 839.6f, "8"))
        yVals.add(Entry(1460.8404f, 738.2f, "9"))
        yVals.add(Entry(1623.156f, 529.6f, "10"))
        yVals.add(Entry(1785.4716f, 323.9f, "11"))
        yVals.add(Entry(1947.7872f, 241.5f, "12"))

        val set1: LineDataSet
        set1 = LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet 1")
        set1.color = Color.BLUE
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE)
        set1.lineWidth = 1f
        set1.circleRadius = 3f
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(true)
        set1.valueTextSize = 0f
        set1.setDrawFilled(true)


        val dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
        dataSets.add(set1)
        val data = LineData(dataSets)

        // set data
        lineChart.data = data
        lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
        lineChart.legend.isEnabled = false
        lineChart.setPinchZoom(true)    
        lineChart.xAxis.setLabelCount(13, true)
        lineChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -90f

        val minXRange = 0f
        val maxXRange = 1947.7872f
        lineChart.setVisibleXRange(minXRange, maxXRange)

        lineChart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

    }
```

I tried with `lineChart.setScaleMinima (1f, 1f)` but it doesn't work.

For more details see image:

[image: For more details see image]